# Vaadin 8 Grid display related item name

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

Trying to get the related items name to display within a Vaadin Grid.

This will get the name of the main item:

```
grid.addColumn(thing::getName).setCaption("Name");
```

This will return the object of the related item:

```
grid.addColumn(thing::getRelatedThing).setCaption("Related Thing Name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple. Placing here in case it might help others or maybe someone has a better way.

```
grid.addColumn(e -> e.getRelatedThing.getName).setCaption("Related Thing Name");
```